# How to set maxlength on input field based on a different combo box value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a payment form which accepts credit card information. The CVV field is set to accept only up to 4 numeric characters. Is there a way in AngularJS to change the maxlength to 3 or 4 based on card type that is chosen in a different combo box?

Thank you!

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="cvv">CVV <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cvv" id="cvv" numbers-only="numbers-only" maxlength="4" ng-model="paymentForm.CVV" required />
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="cardType">Card Type</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="cardType" class="form-control" ng-options="opt for opt in cardTypes" ng-model="paymentForm.CardType"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img ng-src="~/images/credit-card-logos.png" class="logosImage" />
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cvv" id="cvv" numbers-only="numbers-only" ng-maxlength="paymentForm.CardType == 'visa' ? 3 : 4" ng-model="paymentForm.CVV" required />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-maxlength`. E.g. `ng-maxlength="paymentForm.CardType == 1 ? 3 : 4"`

Answer (score 1):

Look this:

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("DemoController", function($scope, $compile){
    $scope.cardTypes = [3, 6, 9];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="DemoController" ng-init="montaAccordion()">
  Max Lenght: {{mxLength}} <select id="cardType" class="form-control" ng-options="opt for opt in cardTypes" ng-model="mxLength"></select>
  
  Text: <input type="text" maxlength="{{mxLength}}"/>
</div>
```